# How can I do this bullet layout with that line there in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I do this bullet layout with that line there in Word?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps by using specialty crafted bullet characters.

You will then need to find a font that contains these three characters for start/middle/end of the list, to use as bullets.

If such a font cannot be found, you'll need to create it.